# How could we define speed without time?

Tags: time, speed

This is a bit of a brain twister but it's a very serious question. Please be precise in your answer.

I do not believe time exists. I believe it is simply an illusion of our perception, the perception of seeing things around us change. The faster things change the more time seems to go by. In some sort, change is the result of the dissipation of energy. Thus what I believe is that what we are really observing is the energy being dissipated and created all around us and we call it time.

Since time doesn't exist (for me). That would mean that the equation of [ speed = distance / time ] is impossible. But nevertheless the concept of speed is fundamental for physics. What could we replace this equation with to no longer have speed dependent of time but of energy?

Comment: If time doesn't exist, how long are you going to wait for an answer?

Comment: What does the word *to change* or a phrase like *being X* mean if there is no time?

Comment: The question is closely related to other questions, if not an exact duplicate, and it seems a clear enough question that has a clear answer. So I'm not sure why it's attracting so many downvotes.

Comment: @JohnRennie Although I did not downvote, I can imagine that OP's bold tone while defending a completely untenable position could be the cause of the downvotes.

Comment: It would help if you clarified whether this is a belief you hold personally or a postulate whose consequences you would like to explore.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty well it was both until John shook the belief, now it's more of a postulate I would like to explore. ;) But I'm not a physicist so there is only so much I know from highschool classes and online articles...

Comment: Julian Barbour's winning essay on the nature of time  describes how classical mechanics can be viewed as timeless: http://www.fqxi.org/data/essay-contest-files/Barbour_The_Nature_of_Time.pdf Many other entries in the fqxi contest provide a lot of interesting ideas: http://www.fqxi.org/community/essay/winners/2008.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that to position objects in spacetime requires four coordinates e.g. $(t, x, y, z)$. So time certainly exists. The point you're addressing is about the flow of time. Incidentally this point is discussed in some detail in the question [Is there a proof of existence of time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71823/is-there-a-proof-of-existence-of-time).

Any object traces out a worldline that is a curve in spacetime, and we can parameterise this curve by using an affine parameter $\tau$ that varies along the curve, then write the coordinates as a function of this parameter, $t(\tau)$, $x(\tau)$, $y(\tau)$ and $z(\tau)$. In fact this is exactly what is done in General Relativity. In GR the affine parameter is normally the [proper time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time), but any parameter can be used and need not have any physical significance. For example photon world lines can be parameterised in this way even that the proper time is everywhere constant for a photon.

Having done this we can now calculate values for $dx/dt$, $dy/dt$, etc and even things like $dx/dy$ if we wish. Then we can define a coordinate velocity as:

$$ v^2 = \left( \frac{dx}{dt} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{dy}{dt} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{dz}{dt} \right)^2$$

So the point is that we can calculate a velocity without worrying about whether there is a flow of time in the sense humans normally use the term. There is no need to replace velocity with any other quantity.

Comment: If there is no flow of time, how is $dx/dt$ defined? In other words: How do you derive the tangent of a function if you have only a single point?

Comment: @pfnuesel: for any object there is a worldline spans ranges of $t$, so it is not the case that an object has only one value of $t$ that doesn't change. The *flow of time* is the claim that time moves forward along the curve. But the worldline is just a set of spacetime points and its existance does not imply motion along it.

Comment: @JohnRennie This is complex! haha but I really appreciate the answer. You blew my mind with your answer for Is there a proof of existence of time? (Genius) Still I wonder, does this mean that we could define velocity based on the fluctuation of energy but that it's not necessary?

Comment: @David: I can't think of any useful way to define velocity as a function of energy. Sorry!

Comment: @David: I would think that part of the problem in defining velocity in terms of energy is that energy is a scalar quantity (only magnitude) while velocity is a vector quantity (magnitude *and* direction).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Length contraction equation of Special Relativity to determine speed.  If you know the dimensions of an object at rest relative to you, you would know its velocity relative to you by finding which dimensions are length contracted and by how much when you measure the body in motion relative to you. But, full disclosure, I think time exists.