# Time- the stubborn illusion?

Tags: general-relativity, soft-question, time, time-travel

BACKGROUND: As I was happily watching "Genius" tele-drama's teaser [Genuis](http://channel.nationalgeographic.com/genius/videos/time-is-but-a-stubborn-illusion/), I came across this very popular and subtle comment:

> The past,present and the future all exist simultaneously. Time is nothing but *a stubborn illusion*.

**NOW**: After cracking up my mind with time, illusions and time dilation, I concluded myself that Time as in Physics (which is a measurement of what clock reads) is not an illusion. Thanks to this wonderful SE post [Is time an illusion?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/176690/is-time-an-illusion) (Referring it here since my question is different from this and is not its dupe) but now a part of me fumbles with the other problem, *Time Travelling*. If time in physics is just a measurement (I don't bother about the other times as time in philosophy-eternalism, the block universe theory, etc.), then why (how) the idea of *time travelling* exists ? Isn't the term a moot considering that one can travel forward or backward by a few kilometers but with time it's impossible. May be time travelling is associated with relativistic/space time (Einstein's baby). But with the Earth as frame of reference (as we haven't yet colonised the space), *time travelling* seems to me a scientific fantasy not any better than Christopher Nolan's movie.

Finally my question is "Is the idea of *Time Travelling* a lie and scientifically unrealistic?"

Comment: Keep in mind that looking at a spacetime system from outside the system looks different than if you're part of the system. We can't "time travel" in the colloquial sense because we are not gods with the ability to edit the time coordinate of an event in spacetime. Our minds perceive time because the mind state changes from one time coordinate to another. Minds that don't change in such a manner are generally considered dead.

Comment: So time depends on a mind that is alive? What of the uranium in the rocks that over time decay? Isn't that how we know the age of the earth, and in different ways all about time? Or are you both clueless?

Comment: @BobBee Time _doesn't depends_  on the state of mind but *Time travelling* does is what Asher says, I suppose. 'cause Time travelling as Asher says can't be possible on/within Earth(with how we define Time in physics).

Comment: I don't have more to say. This discussion doesn't have anything to do with physics.

Comment: @BobBee I partly agree :) and that's why I have tagged  it under soft question. At a macroscopic level it might not be but somewhere deep in the sub atomic microscopic level it might overlap with physics. Anyways there is already a Q/A like this in this same physics SE :P see top -the possible dupe!

Comment: Well, I partly agree, but partly disagree. I disagree on everything that is said about mental effects or reltaiohnships with physical time. But it is true, in what we know of physics, that at Planck time intervals and time sizes time and space may not even be defined, and they might emerge from qaiantum gravity or whatever works at those sizes/times/energies. There's physics being done on that, with still no experiments, but with cosmology in Planckian times a possible telescope to it. It would affect the mind the same way it would affect those rocks I mentioned.

Comment: Continued. If physics had an effect that the brain uses to be more than what we observe in anything else it'd be pretty amazing, and from energetic considerations unlikely. From complexity? It's just more not different. So, unless you are arguing from a non-physics point of view, from what we know, it's unlikely.

Comment: @BobBee  If this question isn't closed, I would have requested you to write the answer ;) Though I don't understand much about what you had told about Planck time (I'm a kid when it comes to quantum physics), I'm excited to think how man made science can have effect on human brain. Nice one for thought experiment!