# expansion of space and time vs passage of time

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, time, time-dilation

Is passage of time is due to expansion of space and time?And the "dilation of time(by general relativity)" due to the force of gravity held against the expansion itself,like time slows down near massive objects because of gravity?.

Comment: The passage of time is due to the fact that the universe is not in thermal equilibrium, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the answers to [Is there a proof of existence of time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71823/is-there-a-proof-of-existence-of-time) to get some idea of how time works in relativity. In particular you have to distinguish between the time coordinate and the *flow of time*. In relativity the flow of time doesn't exist.

When we talk about the flow of time we normally mean the changes measured by some mechanism (i.e. a clock) as a function of coordinate time. Mechanical devices work by flowing down a free energy gradient, which in practice normally means flowing up an entropy gradient. So insofar as the flow of time has any physical meaning it is associated with an increase in entropy and is unrelated to the expansion of spacetime.

Time dilation has a specific meaning in relativity. It is the relationship between the coordinate time measured by an observer and the proper time measured along a world line. The popular image of clocks running slow is a perfectly reasonable metaphor, but like all metaphors ultimately misleading.