# Is time really necessary?

Tags: time

In classical mechanics the coordinates of a particle are functions of time. That path is a solution of the equations of motion. In principle then it is just a parameter and can be eliminated giving a direct relation between the coordinates E.g. If you do this for a particle subject to uniform downward acceleration you obtain the upside down parabolic relation of x with y. No time.
 So is time really necessary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is time, does it flow, and if so what defines its direction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235511/)

Comment: See also [Is there a proof of existence of time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71823/)

Comment: If my friend and I both go to the bus station and then leave, but possibly at different times, how can you tell if we actually met, without invoking time?

Comment: For the record I think the downvotes are unwarranted. It's a duplicate, but it's still a perfectly good question. The question is alluding to the idea of [the block universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternalism_(philosophy_of_time)), which as it happens I subscribe to myself.

Comment: Ask Julian Barbour, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_Barbour, he would agree with you. Personally, I am not sure this is a physics question, and that  any answers will reflect the fact that the variable t is very useful in  mathematical terms, but physically hard to explain.

Comment: I think it is a very good question. A mechanics without time!

Answer (score 1):

While some equations that contain an explicit time coordinate could be reformulated in a way that doesn't explicitly reference time, I believe this is missing the broader point about why time matters.  Arguably, the purpose of physics (and science more generally) is to create a framework by which we can understand, and make testable predictions about, the physical world.  We, as humans, care about *when* things will happen, and so we often want our predictions to include a component of "when".  Moreover, the information available to us is often the state of things *at a certain time* (i.e., the initial conditions), which introduces time into the problem.

If I throw a ball in the air, I don't just want to know what path it will follow - I want to know when it's coming back down.  Wouldn't you?

Comment: If you ask this question to the average jo in the street he would regard you as crazy to doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a three dimensional map. If all the derivatives (dx/dy, dy/dz, dz/dx) were zero it would just be a flat land with no information. Without time even nonzero derivatives have a unique information  fixed for ever on this map,  life cannot be described, as  no change ever. Introducing a dx/dt, etc allows for changes in the map including finally life.