# Photon mass and life time

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, speed-of-light, mass, photons

In this [article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.2821), the author tried to explain that, Einstein's theory may not valid because he says "photon can decay because it may have minute amount of mass". I'm totally in a conundrum state that how to take this article? 
Anyone can explain a bit please.

Comment: The current text of this questions is deeply misleading. The article *assumes* the correctness of relativity which investigating a theory in which the photon has mass.

Comment: Dear Raisa - just scanning the text, I can't find mention of relativity. I presume then you mean that a photon mass would imply variable lightspeed, thus overturning SR and GR. Not so. $c$ is simply the speed of a massless particle - whether or not light has mass has no impact on relativity - there are still very basic symmetry reasons for SR that have nothing to do with light - see a description of [relativity without consideration of light](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/71226/26076) of mine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can postulate the existence of a photon mass and then use experiments to put an upper bound on it.  The mass-modified Lagrangian is called the Proca Lagrangian (see Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics, second edition page 597).  In the static case you get a Yukawa type potential.  If the photon has nonzero mass, then it should decay.  Of course, this would change a lot of what we think we know, but the limits on the mass are very small.  Here is a nice overview of mass limits on the photon and graviton.  http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.1003

Incidentally, some people like a symmetric form of Maxwell that includes a magnetic "charge density" (monopole).  Similar efforts can put bounds on the existance of monopoles.

Comment: Updated constraints on photon mass and lifetime: http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.2821