# What $E=mc^2$ has to do with nuclear formation?

Tags: nuclear-physics, mass-energy, binding-energy

I am a bit confused that what actually the Einstein's equation meant to describe binding energy wht is that $c^2$ for as when nucleon combine what is the need of speed of light in equation?

Comment: The $c$ in relativity isn't really the speed of light. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35404/ . Also, $E=mc^2$ is not specifically about nuclear reactions. It also applies when you burn a match. It applies to any form of energy.

Answer (score 0):

The equation E=mc^2 is useful when  it relates energy and mass in special relativity, when m is the specific *rest mass* of a particle or a nucleus, i.e. the length of any [four vector](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) that would describe the particle in all Lorentz covariant frames.

*c is not the velocity* of the particle described by the equation. *It is a constant imposed by the algebra of special relativity*, a scale factor, that happens to be the velocity of light in vacuum. In particle physics one often works in [computational systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units#Summary_table) where c is set equal to 1.

The [general formula](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/tdil.html#c3) has m as the *relativistic mass,* where the velocity of a particle enters as v.

[image: relmass]

This is not useful for nuclear and particle physics, where the sums for binding energies have to use the m_0, invariant mass to Lorentz transformations.

Comment: Thanks Anna for feedback though I am a highschool level buddy but still got I think some of it.